# Use nested attributes and hierarchies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables is 
- Training_Assessments : id, name
- Standards: id, name, training_assessment_id, parent_id

And `Model Standards`

```
class Standard < ApplicationRecord
  ATTRIBUTE_PARAMS = %i(id name proportion parent_id).freeze

  belongs_to :training_assessment

  has_closure_tree
end
```

`Model TrainingAssessment`

```
class TrainingAssessment < ApplicationRecord
  ATTRIBUTE_PARAMS =
    [
      :id, :name,
      standards_attributes: Standard::ATTRIBUTE_PARAMS
    ].freeze

  has_many :standards, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :standards, allow_destroy: true
end
```

I one training assessments have many standards, and each standard have many child standard have parent_id of parent standard. I try created at console but child standard don't have id of training assessments nested.
So how i can do it ? And how is the params structure?

Comment: I never use join in nested forms.

Answer (score 0):

You need an association from one standard to it's parent standard in your model:

`belongs_to :parent_standard, foreign_key: :parent_id`

Then you can delegate:

`delegate :training_assessment, to: :parent_standard`

EDIT:

Using closure_tree gem: `child.root.training_assessment_id` is the parents training_assessment_id

Comment: `parent_id `issues is clear. because i use ClosureTree gem, it help me can create root node and child node. I only want then i create child node and have training_assessment_id of root node.

Comment: I have not used that gem, but reading through the documentation can't you just use `child.root.training_assessment_id`?

Comment: yes, i can do it. So i assign `training_asessment_id` by manual for each standard records. ....  There are many thing that i don't know  how to describe. I need time do think that. Thank you for help :)